# Continuous Dependence of $x''+K\sin x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot analyze continuous dependence of solutions on the initial data for the equation

$$x''+K\sin x=0$$  on the interval $[0,2π]$.

I have tried to convert this equation to first order system. But coefficient matrix is not constant then i cannot conclude any outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pendulum equation and there isn't a simple solution. If you make the assumption that $x$ is small, you can approximate $\sin x$ with its Taylor expansion and getting a simple solution in terms of trig functions.

[enter link description here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics))